# RavenDB Query Suggest Multiple Words

Tags: ravendb

I have some code that is searching a RavenDB database with the following index:

```
public class Products_Search :
                AbstractIndexCreationTask<Product, Products_Search.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Query { get; set; }
    }

    public Products_Search()
    {
        Map = products =>
              from product in products
              select new
              {
                  Query = new
                  {
                      Categories = product.Categories.Boost(5),
                      Brands = product.Brands.Boost(8),
                      product.Description,
                      Name = product.Name.Boost(10),
                      product.SKU
                  },
                  product.Price
              };

        Index(x => x.Query, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

If I query against this like this (both strawberry protein are spelt wrong):

```
var query = RavenSession.Query<Products_Search.Result, Products_Search>()
                        .Where(x => x.Query == "strawbery protien");

var suggestions = query.Suggest().Suggestions.Take(5)
```

I would like the suggestions be be "strawberry protein" not one of "strawberry" and another of "protein". Is this possible with RavenDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to do something similar and I use the `LuceneQuery` syntax to achieve it. I am using the `OR` operator but you will want to use the `AND` operator.

**The Index**

```
public class ContentItem_BySearchParam : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ContentItem>
{
    public ContentItem_BySearchParam()
    {
        Map = contentItems =>
                from contentItem in contentItems
                select new {contentItem.Title, contentItem.Description, contentItem.Keywords};

        Store("Title", FieldStorage.Yes);
        Index("Title", FieldIndexing.Analyzed);

        Store("Description", FieldStorage.Yes);
        Index("Description", FieldIndexing.Analyzed);

        Store("Keywords", FieldStorage.Yes);
        Index("Keywords", FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

**The Query**

```
public SearchResults GetResults(IDocumentSession db, params string[] searchTerms)
{
    var query =
            GetLuceneQuery("Title", searchTerms) + " OR " +
            GetLuceneQuery("Description", searchTerms) + " OR " +
            GetLuceneQuery("Keywords", searchTerms);

    var results = db
        .Advanced
        .LuceneQuery<ContentItem, RavenIndexes.ContentItem_BySearchParam>()
        .Where(query)
        .ToList();

      .... do other stuff
}

private string GetLuceneQuery(string field, string[] terms, string searchOperator = "")
{
    var join = " " + searchOperator;
    var prefix = field + ":(" + searchOperator;
    return prefix + String.Join(@join, terms) + ")";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ilivewithian,

We build the suggestions based on the terms that we use.
You can index the Query field twice, once using Analyzed (in which case it breaks it into words) and once using default, in which case it uses the full term.
That might give you what you want.