# RavenDb Suggestions - return multiple-contexts words

Tags: autocomplete, nlp, ravendb, autosuggest

I'm trying to get context based suggestions result from RavenDb, the purpose is ui dropdown with auto suggestion from large amount of data on server, each keystroke (in 400ms) is  sent to retrieve suggestions.

The suggestion i need is with multiple words by context.
let's say i'm looking for 'Harry Potter', i have documents with just 'Harry' and some docs with only 'Potter', and documents with both.
But if i type 'harre poter' i would get one word suggestions.

i tried searching with multiple words ([demonstrated here](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/indexes/querying/suggestions#suggest-over-multiple-words) - suggest.Term = "(word1 word2)";), but the result is list of **one words**. i want to type 'harre poter' and get suggestion of 'Harry Potter'

i even tried querying multiple times with each word, but the result are not context based, in other word - there is no connection between them.

```
 var words = text.Split(new String[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

            var sugegstions = new List<SuggestionQuery>();

            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                var suggest = new SuggestionQuery();
                suggest.Field = "Body";
                suggest.Term = word;
                suggest.Popularity = true;
                suggest.MaxSuggestions = 5;
                suggest.Distance = StringDistanceTypes.Levenshtein;

                sugegstions.Add(suggest);
            }

            var results = new List<SuggestionQueryResult>();

            foreach (var suggest in sugegstions)
            {
                SuggestionQueryResult result =
                     s.Query<Book, Books_ByBody>().Suggest(suggest);

                results.Add(result);

            }
```

i looked in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935048/ravendb-query-suggest-multiple-words), and tried it too, but the results are the docs not suggestions.

my index is : `

public class Books_ByBody : AbstractIndexCreationTask
        {

```
        public Books_ByBody()
        {
            Map = books from book in books
                            select new
                            {
                                book.Body,
                            };
            Indexes.Add(x => x.Body, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
            Suggestion(x => x.Body);
        }
    }
```

`